# Laravel, Lavacharts, displaying multiple charts using a for loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display multiple charts using a for loop in laravel using Lavacharts. I dont know what is the problem but only the last chart is displayed. The last chart however is correctly displayed.

(My controller mostly generates two lines in a chart for each chart. One is the standard value and another is the actual value. All those values are intialized before these loops and they work correctly.)
Here is the controller:

```
$i=0;

foreach ($user_farms as $user_farm){


$user_farm_id = $user_farm->id;
$user_flocks = \App\Flock::where('farm_id', '=', $user_farm_id)->get();
$no_flocks = \App\Flock::where('farm_id', '=', $user_farm_id)->get()->count();

$j=0;

foreach ($user_flocks as $user_flock){

    $user_flock_id = $user_flock->id;
    $weights = \App\Weight::where('flock_id', '=', $user_flock_id)->orderBy('week_id', 'asc')->get();

    $weights_first = $weights ->first();
    $start_week = $weights_first->week_id;

    foreach($weights as $weight ){

        $age = $weight->week_id - $start_week ;
        $actual[$age] = $weight->female;

    }   


    $graph = Lava::DataTable();
    $graph->addStringColumn('Weeks')
         ->addNumberColumn('Standard')
         ->addNumberColumn('Actual')
         ->addRow(['1',  $standard[1], ($actual[1]>0? $actual[1] : null) ])
         ->addRow(['2',  $standard[2], $actual[2]])
         ->addRow(['3',  $standard[3], $actual[3]])
         ->addRow(['4',  $standard[4], $actual[4]])
         ->addRow(['5',  $standard[5], $actual[5]])
         ->addRow(['6',  $standard[6], $actual[6]])
         ->addRow(['7',  $standard[7], $actual[7]])
         ->addRow(['8',  $standard[8], $actual[8]])
         ->addRow(['9',  $standard[9], $actual[9]])
         ->addRow(['10',  $standard[10], $actual[10]]);


        Lava::LineChart($i.'graph'.$j, $graph, [
            'title' => 'Weights of '. $user_flock->name
        ]);
    $j++;
}

$i++;
}
```

And here is the view, I am using blade templating:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $no_farms; $i++)
    @for ($j = 0; $j < $no_flocks; $j++)


        <div id="graph_div"></div>
        @linechart($i.'graph'.$j, 'graph_div')


    @endfor    
@endfor
```

Comment: You can use `$lava->renderAll();` in the view like discribed [here](https://github.com/kevinkhill/lavacharts#view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same div with id 'graph_div' in each pass of the `for`.
So you should change the id of the div for each graph you need ("graph_div_$i_$j", for example.)

```
    <div id="graph_div_{{$i}}_{{$j}}"></div>
    @linechart($i.'graph'.$j, 'graph_div_'.$i.'_'.$j)
```